# Application_EndRequest Doesn't Fire on a 404

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session

I am using ASP MVC 2 and Nhibernate. I have created an HTTP Module as demonstrated in Summer of NHibernate 13 that looks like so:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
     context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);
     context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(Application_EndRequest);
}

private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ISession session = StaticSessionManager.OpenSession();
    session.BeginTransaction();
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
}

private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ISession session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(StaticSessionManager.SessionFactory);
  if (session != null)
  try
  {
      session.Transaction.Commit();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       session.Transaction.Rollback();
   }
   finally
   {
       session.Flush();
       session.Close();
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<add name="UnitOfWork" type="HttpModules.UnitOfWork"/>
```

My problem is that Application_EndRequest never gets called on a 404 error so if my view does not render I completely block database access until my flush takes place. I am fairly new to NHibernate so I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: I'm curious why Application_EndRequest doesn't get called on a 404.  Perhaps that's true only for a specific sub-status code.  For example, with 404.13 (request too large), Application_EndRequest is called.  In fact, it's called **instead** of Application_BeginRequest and it's called almost immediately, long before the server could have possibly received the entire request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dispose and rollback the session in application_error. change session.close into session.dispose and check if it's not already disposed.