# LazyInitializationException in ASP.NET app with NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

Using NHibernate with ASP.NET 4.

I have had no issues retrieving objects, but I've just got to a point with nested objects that I can't figure out.

I am using *lazy=true* and when accessing a lazy-load collection I get the message:

```
Initializing[type#3]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: [type], no session or session was closed
```

Even if I call SessionFactory.OpenSession() immediately prior to the object being accessed, it makes no difference. I have also tried accessing the collection in a *using ISession* block to no luck.

Edit to add - I do have current_session_context_class = web set in web.config, and I am using CurrentSessionContext.Bind on BeginRequest.

Can anyone offer some advice?

**Not an MVC app**

I read this - don't know how accurate it is, and it is Hibernate:
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2878

It says something about a bug in many-to-many relationships.

Here is my HBM mapping:

```
<bag name="Objects" table="ObjectInstance" cascade="all" lazy="true">
  <key column="branchId" />
  <many-to-many class="InventoryObjectInstance" column="objectInstanceId" />
</bag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that happen after you perform some save/update operations? Where and when are you closing the session? To me, it sounds like you close the session right after save call or in some other method before the web page gets rendered. In other words, make sure you are using Open Session in View pattern and close the session only in the end of current web-request. You can also check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525630/how-implement-the-open-session-in-view-pattern-in-nhibernate).

Comment: Cheers Denis. Nope, there is no save operation, and as I said even explicitly creating a session prior to the call still gives me this exception.

Comment: You shouldn't re-open the session b/c in this case it's a different session that cant be reused in those objects that expect that OLD session - you have to keep the same session context within the current request life cycle. You just need to locate those code blocks (usings, explicit calls to .Close() method) which are closing your session and move it to EndRequest in Global.asax http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx

Comment: Found a dirty using statement hidden away that I'd somehow missed..  Thanks everyone, cheers for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When object graphs are retrieved they keep a reference to the session that spawned them. They use that session for lazy loading of their properties. If the original session is closed, you will get this error (or one just like it) when trying to access them. Opening a new session will not help.

You can try to find where the original request session is being closed and stop that. Are you in the same request though? Failing that you can try to connect your object to a new session -- I think it is `Session.Lock(YourObject)`. Alternatively you could retrieve the object again from the new session.

Comment: Still in the same session, and I have break pointed all the code where the session is closed and not being tripped.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are getting a new ISession when you call SessionFactory.OpenSession(). Is your first use of the session wrapping access to it in a `using` block? Why are you calling OpenSession again anyway -- what happened to the reference to the session?